# Calculating sum of rows and putting them into another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the sum of values of a specific column in multiple rows

```
     Name        Score
     john        10
     ted         20
```

I want to calculate all of scores and store in another column, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you show us sample data along with any query you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum a database column in MysQL like so:
`SELECT SUM(Score) as Total FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `SUM` keyword

```
SELECT name, score, SUM(score) as Total_Score
FROM names;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82141/1/0

Answer (score 1):

This query should work for you

```
UPDATE table_name1 SET column1= (SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name2) WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

This is basically as per your requirement combination of two queries. Inner query calculates the sum and outer query puts data into a column of specified table.

Comment: If this was helpful remember to mark it as an answer for other to benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Score) AS total FROM table_name
```

where table_name is the name of your table, which you haven't informed in your question.